# Total Duration of Playlist in VLC Player?

Tags: vlc-media-player

In VLC, is it possible to know the total duration of the Playing of a Playlist?

[image: Playlist in VLC Media Player]

I have looked around, in the settings, but didn't find anything.

Comment: No need to script or anything just a simple settings can show your total length of the playlist. See this post it have explained well and I found my solution here.
[Tutorial to show playlist total time](https://superuser.com/a/867142/815282)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In case you still can't locate it:

As of VLC version 2.1 for Windows and Linux, you can see the total playlist duration next to the playlist menu item on the left side-bar in the playlist view.

(I just spent a few minutes trying to find it!)

VLC version 2.1.2 on Win 8.1

[image]

Comment: Yes, upgrading works. On Ubuntu etc, need to do something like http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-vlc-2-1-2-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: As of VLC v2.1.5, the Mac version doesn't have this (running MacOS X 10.8).

Comment: Mac OS: https://ibb.co/miofEG

Comment: Fedora 36 doesn't have it.

Comment: if left hand bar is missing, put the mouse on the far left and you should be able to drag it back out to the right. Just ran into this.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another VLC Player extension to display the total playlist duration: **[github: bentrevor/vlc-extension](https://github.com/bentrevor/vlc-extension)**.

Once installed, on OS X, it works/looks like this:

[image: extension for vlc player to see total playlist duration]

Comment: Works on VLC 2.1.5 on OS X 10.7 Thanks!

Comment: Works with VLC 3 on ubuntu. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

This [script](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=97639&start=20#p341783) may be of interest to you. It is supposed to enable total playlist time in VLC. Also worth a look is this [forum post.](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=96760)

Answer (score 1):

If you see the left panel, but no time is visible:

```
Playlist
```

It may be the case when length of some of the songs in the playlist are not known (loaded). Go through the playlist and play those songs, VLC will load the length and when you do it for all the songs, the total length will be displayed:

```
Playlist [35:45]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Select multiple video/audio files then open it with Vlc.
2. Go to View Menu and click on Playlist.
3. You will see small video screen on left and playlist  on right side
4. Check top left corner below Menu bar You will see Playlist word.
5. You need to drag down using mouse from that Playlist word.