# Total playlist duration in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I know where the total duration is shown, but I just loaded around a thousand tracks into the playlist and its not even trying to load the tracks until they are played. How do I get the total duration without waiting several hours for it to play/clicking thousands of times?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you get no data when you drop the files?…
like this…

[image]

---

- Open Prefs  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>
- Select Show Settings > All [at the bottom] & then
- Check Playlist > Automatically Pre-Parse files
- Quit & relaunch VLC

[image]

It should then auto-fill the information as you add files…

[image]

Comment: doesn't seem to work with aac files but i suppose it is due to the format

Comment: Works exactly the same for m4a files; just tested

Comment: m4a is a container which contain info like duration while aac is just a raw MPEG-4 Part 3 bitstream with audio stream encoded, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110399/what-is-the-difference-between-m4a-and-aac-audio-files

Comment: ahhh… so you're saying it can't extract metadata from a file which contains no metadata. Now, why didn't I figure that out myself?